# angular ivh tree view how to Defer DOM Tree Binding or delay transclusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, tree, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am using the ivh tree library for displaying hierarchichal data.
https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview

I have a tree structure of approx ~2,000 nodes. and i get that data all at once. I need to do some performance optimization.

Is it possible to do lazy transclusion, i know this is a feature of angular 1.5, but can this be achieved using similar strategy used here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2557-defer-dom-tree-binding-in-angularjs-with-delayed-transclusion.htm?